# How to set new index in previous array using for each loop

Tags: php, foreach

here is my code

```
array 1:
 Array
 (

   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 42166
        [Company_Website] => http://www.amphenol-highspeed.com/
        [company_name] => Amphenol High Speed Interconnect
        [city_name] => New York
        [country_name] => USA
        [comp_img] => 
    )

 )
```

array 2:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Product_Name] => CX to CX,Amphenol High  Speed Active,Serial Attached SCSI
        [company_id] => 42166
    )

    )
```

php code:

```
    $total = count($result);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
     $i++;
      $company_id= implode(",",(array)$value['id']);
     if ($i != $total)
      echo',';
    }
```

code to fetch array 2:

```
      foreach ($res as $key1=>$value1) {

        echo  $total;
        $event[$value['company_name']] = $value1['Product_Name'];

        if($value1['company_id']==$company_id )
        {
          echo " match";
          //$key[['company_name']]= $value1['Product_Name'];


        }
        else
        {
         echo "not matched";
        }
    }
```

- what i need create a new index if company_id is match with id of another array.
- that is product_name.
- if product name is there just create index otherwise show null.
- i want show in key=> value .
- output should be like:

  ```
     Array
   (
    [0] => Array
     (
      [id] => 42166
      [Company_Website] => http://www.amphenol-highspeed.com/
      [company_name] => Amphenol High Speed Interconnect
      [city_name] => New York
      [country_name] => USA
      [comp_img] =>
     [Product_Name] => CX to CX,Amphenol High  Speed Active,Serial Attached SCSI 
    )

  )
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your all problems with keys in arrays will disappear when you will start using company ids as a keys.

To reindex you arrays, you can use:

```
$array1 = array_combine(array_column($array1, 'id'), $array1);
$array2 = array_combine(array_column($array2, 'company_id'), $array2);
```

In the output you will get:

```
array 1:

 Array
 (
   [42166] => Array
    (
      [id] => 42166
      ...
    )
 )
```

And `array 2` will looks similiar - id as a key.

So accessing to the elements using ids as a keys is a piece of cake right now.

Comment: can please guide me according what i want i just want to append new key =>value in prev array using if else cond that all